# SharePoint 2013 Term Store Navigation does not show drop down links after branding

Tags: 2013, navigation, branding, design

I've setup the global navigation in my Sharepoint 2013 site using Managed Navigation and the Term Store Management Tool. Most of my top menu items have sub menu items that would normally appear as a drop down when hovering over the top menu item.

My issue is that the drop down menu does not appear to work after I apply branding to my 2013 site. With no branding the drop down menus work just fine.

I created an HTML page, used the Design Manager setup my branding and also used the menu snippet and applied it to my HTML page. I can see all of my top level items which are being driven by the Term Store but no sub menu drop downs.

Can anyone please provide some help.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your problem solved? Because I am facing exact issue and looking for solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue.

I went into seattle.html and copied the topnav code from their

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaTopNavigation" BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-displayInline" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource" Id="topNavigationDelegate">-->
    <!--SPM:<Template_Controls>-->
        <!--SPM:<asp:SiteMapDataSource 
            ShowStartingNode="False"
            SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider" 
            id="topSiteMap" 
            runat="server"
            StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002"/>-->
    <!--SPM:</Template_Controls>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:DelegateControl>-->
<a name="startNavigation"></a> 
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">-->
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:AspMenu 
        ID="TopNavigationMenu" 
        Runat="server" 
        EnableViewState="false"
        DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
        AccessKey="&lt;%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%&gt;"
        UseSimpleRendering="true"
        UseSeparateCss="false"
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        StaticDisplayLevels="2"
        AdjustForShowStartingNode="true"
        MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"
        SkipLinkText="" />-->
        <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/menu-21.css" /><div id="zz7_TopNavigationMenu" class=" noindex ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox"><ul id="zz9_RootAspMenu" class="root ms-core-listMenu-root static"><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" title="Default Publishing Site" href="#" accesskey="1"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Default Publishing Site</span></span></a></li></ul></div><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
<!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
```

-->

Replace the snippet with this code

Answer (score 0):

When you created your snippet, there is a preview screen. That should show you the result of your snippet, BEFORE you copy and paste that snippet into your site.

Those snippets are configurable for number of levels to show. you may want to check that the snippet is configured the number of levels you want.\

The following is from the snippet guidance for Top Navigation snippet in SharePoint 2013:

> Top Navigation
>
> About this Component
>
> The navigation snippets provide common navigation links and menu items
>   on a site page.
>
> The contents of the navigation menu are defined in Navigation
>   Settings. There, you can choose between navigation content defined by
>   site structure or navigation content defined by site metadata and
>   keywords.
>
> You can change how the menu looks and functions (including the number
>   of flyout levels via the StaticDisplayLevels property).